# Query table from model or controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have table `role_user` which has two columns `user_id` and `role_id`. `user_id` is the user id from `users` table and `role_id` is the id from `roles` table.

I want to query `role_user` and show the role name next to each user. Example

table `users`

```
user_id username ...
   1      Test user
```

table `roles`

```
role_id  role_name
   1       Admin
```

table `role_user`

```
user_id   role_id
  1          1
```

I want to show on page

```
Test user - Admin
```

I have added this in my `Users` model

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Role', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

and this in the controller

```
public function users()
{
    $userRole = User::find(1)->role;

    return View::make('users', [
        'userRole' => $userRole
    ]);
}
```

Currently I've got this which is obvious why:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `roles` where `roles`.`user_id` is null and `roles`.`user_id` is not null limit 1)

The question is how to query `role_user` table from controller or from model and while displaying the users to display role name too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your table so one user can have many roles (using a pivot which is your `role_user` table.

If a user can only have one role you can remove the role_user table and add a column `role_id` to your users table.

Using your current implementation change `role` relationship in user model to following.

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

In your controller

```
public function users()
{
    $users= User::with('roles')->get();

    return View::make('users', [
        'users' => $users
    ]);
}
```

To simply show the names of roles use `implode` method of returned collection

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    {{ $user->roles->implode('name', ',') }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: When I try to show the name of role like `$userRoles->name` in my view got this error: `Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: `belongsToMany` relation returns a collection which does not have a `name` property. Either you have to loop it or use `implode` method. Updated the answer with `implode` method

Comment: Do i need to put this implode right after the query? I have foreach which loop trough users and want to use this `$userRoles` on each user. With implode after the query and then in my blade `{{ $userRole->name }}` I've got same error

Comment: If you are looping users then you can get the roles inside each user `$user->roles->implode('name', ',')`. Don't forget to eager load `roles` relation.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks. Is there a way this `$user->roles->implode('name', ',')` implode to be in controller and somehow in blade view to have something like `$user->role->name` or `$user->name`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153836/discussion-between-chanafdo-and-ivan).

Answer (score -1):

You are using a pivot table to maintain the relationship so you need to 
 `belongsToMany`relation and defining a custom accessor for it, like so:

```
//User model file
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(App\Role::class);
}

public function getRoleAttribute()
{
    return $this->roles()->first();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but something isn't right here. Got this error now: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'role_user.user_user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `roles`.*, `role_user`.`user_user_id` as `pivot_user_user_id`, `role_user`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id` from `roles` inner join `role_user` on `roles`.`id` = `role_user`.`role_id` where `role_user`.`user_user_id` = 95)`

Comment: Do you have role table and associated model As `Role` ? You should have Role model and role table. you no need add any model for pivot table , which will be automatically decided by laravel.

Comment: Yes, I have Role model too and table `roles`

Comment: I used a laravel convention , for creating a Models and Tables , I considered as users-> id,name... and roles->id,name.., role_user->user_id,role_id and respective models `User`,`Role`. Then it will work perfect .

Comment: Sadly but my users table doesn't use `id` it's using `user_id`